# Regular expression to extract the word from the string ${VALUE(word_to_be_extracted)} in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

What is the best regex to extract the word inside that string?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("pattern here");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(${VALUE(word_to_be_extracted)});

                    while(matcher.find()) {
                        System.out.println(matcher.group());

                    }
```

Comment: you mean if the string is "applebanana" and you want to get apple it will return apple?

Comment: Can you reword your question? What word do you want? Any word?

Comment: I meant that I need to get apple from a string ${VALUE(apple)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/\$\{VALUE\((.*)\)\}/`

The first capture group will be your word

Comment: By his while loop, however, I would guess that he wants all matches, not just one.